# How to write filter for System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs

Tags: c#

Firstly, note that I'm completely new to C#, so may be I don't understand some basics. I want to filter symbols for `TextBox` control which should contain only correct C++ class name. Allowed symbols are digits, latin letters and underscore (first symbol shouldn't be the digit), however I want allow user to use navigation and edit keys, like `home` and `delete`. I've already found few topics but still cann't figure it out. My Last attempt is to use `PreviewKeyDown` event to catch `shift` and `PreviewKeyUp` to actually filter keys:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

public partial class AddCppClassDialog : DialogWindow
{
    private bool shiftEnabled = false;
    public AddCppClassDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClassNameTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += KeyDownPreviewHandler;
        ClassNameTextBox.PreviewKeyUp += KeyUpPreviewHandler;
    }

    private void KeyDownPreviewHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
        {
            shiftEnabled = true;
        }
    }
    private void KeyUpPreviewHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9 && !shiftEnabled)
            || (e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z)
            || e.Key == Key.Delete
            || e.Key == Key.Back
            || e.Key == Key.Left
            || e.Key == Key.Up
            || e.Key == Key.Right
            || e.Key == Key.Down
            || e.Key == Key.Home
            || e.Key == Key.End
            || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9)
            || (e.Key == Key.OemMinus && shiftEnabled))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        shiftEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

This code still allow to print `-` and special symbols like `@` and `#`. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following methods:

```
    private bool shiftEnabled = false;
    public AddCppClassDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClassNameTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += KeyDownPreviewHandler;
        ClassNameTextBox.PreviewKeyUp += KeyUpPreviewHandler;
        ClassNameTextBox.KeyDown += KeyDownHandler;
    }

    private void KeyDownPreviewHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
        {
            shiftEnabled = true;
     
        } else if(e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)) // First symbol cann't be a digit, any numpad keys have no sense.
            {
                e.Handled = (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9;
                return;
            }
        }
        
        if ((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9 && !shiftEnabled)
            || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9)
            || (e.Key == Key.OemMinus && shiftEnabled)
            || (e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z)
            || e.Key == Key.Delete
            || e.Key == Key.Back
            || e.Key == Key.Left
            || e.Key == Key.Up
            || e.Key == Key.Right
            || e.Key == Key.Down
            || e.Key == Key.Home
            || e.Key == Key.End)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void KeyUpPreviewHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
        {
            shiftEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```